# Mysql find value in multiple database (same structure)

Tags: mysql, database

With the plan that I have with my hosting, I have size limit for the databases, but I do not have limit in number of database.
To solve this I have thought of dividing my databases by countries and each database has the same structure.
The problem is how to look up data in all these databases.
For example, each database can have a users table.
The problem is how to find a user (for example) in all these databases. (Can be 250 of databases)

```
/*This would be for one database*/
SELECT user_name FROM DB1.users WHERE user_name = 'my_user_name' LIMIT 1;
```

**Is there any way to search 'my_user_name' from all databases ?** 
(Users is only one example ... the value to search can be products , city , coordinates etc etc)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to open separate connections to each database and re-execute the query for each database, then combine the data together in your own code - this will be messy and you will run into problems with colliding primary-keys unless you prefix them all with a database-name qualifier.

You haven't said what language you're using, but in psuedocode it would be like this:

```
let connectionStrings: String[] {
    "server=dbServer,database=asia",
    "server=dbServer,database=europe",
    "server=dbServer,database=northAmerica"
}

let users = new List<User>()

foreach(connectionString in connectionStrings) {

    let connection = new DBConnection( connectionString )
    let reader = connection.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM Users" )
    while( reader.read() ) {

        let user = new User() {
            userId = connection.databaseName + reader.get("userId"),
            userName = reader.get("userName"),
            // etc
        }
        users.add( user );
    }
}

return users;
```

Repeat this for all the queries you want to do.

This is a bad idea - databases are cheap, most shared hosting providers offer gigabyte-sized databases even in their $5/mo plans.

Comment: "_This is a bad idea_" thanks for the warning.

I have 1GB limit size but for example only the geonames DB  (from geonames.org) have approx 1.5-2 GB. so i have divided it by countries and thought to do the same with users products etc.I think that in the end I will do a General database with less information ( two three columns) where I will save  only  the references that corresponds to each country database.

Answer (score 1):

As long as they're on the same server you can use the inner join command:

`SELECT a.userID, b.usersFirstName, b.usersLastName  FROM databaseA.dbo.TableA a inner join database B.dbo.TableB b  ON a.userID=b.userID`

Comment: Cross-database joins are generally expensive though, and there's no referential integrity either.

Comment: This is completely true. The best option would simply to purchase a hosting plan that suited MTK's needs, but this is the only option I know of besides your reply.

Comment: Ok and thank's. I understand that what I was looking for it can not be possible (or if is, the cost is tremendous) imagine inner joins for dbA0..dbA9 ... dbZ0 ... dbZ9 (250 Databases) :D